# How to depend on two versions of PyTorch using Poetry?

Tags: pytorch, python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as my dependency manager. The project is a small computer vision model for object detection.

I would like to publish it as a Python package and, when the end user installs my package I would like to let her choose between the GPU/CPU versions, something like:
`pip install my_package[cpu]` or `pip install my_package[gpu]`.

My `pyproject.toml` file looks something like that:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu"
priority = "explicit"

[tool.poetry.group.cpu.dependencies]
torch = {version = "^2.1.2+cpu", source = "torch", optional=true}
torchvision = {version = "^0.16.2+cpu", source = "torch", optional=true}

[tool.poetry.group.gpu.dependencies]
torch = {version = "^2.1.2", optional=true}
torchvision = {version = "^0.16.2", optional=true}

[tool.poetry.extras]
cpu = ["torch", "torchvision"]
gpu = ["torch", "torchvision"]
```

Clearly it is not going to work.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.